# Debugging an Access form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an access database with a bunch of forms which I did not build. One of the fields on the form pops-up an error during data entry. I opened the form in design mode and looked at the Events. But I do not see any of the events generating that error text.I searched the entire project for that error text and cant get a hit.Where else could the error be bubbling up from. From the text of the error I can tell that it was developer written and not a Microsoft error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that form field is bound (meaning its Control Source property is a field in the form's record source), examine the design of the table which includes that field.

In table design, a field can be assigned a Validation Rule property and a Validation Text property.  See whether the Validation Text property matches the mystery error text.

Note, there can also be a Validation Rule and Validation Text defined for the table itself. So in addition to checking the field properties, also inspect the property sheet for the table itself.

Comment: Looked at the validation rules at column and table level and do not see any rules in place. :(

Comment: Does the form field control have anything for Validation Rule and Validation Text?

Comment: Like I said the message shows up on an on focus of a drop down complaining about the date entered in another field.

Comment: If you upload a copy of the db to a file sharing site and give us a link, I will see if I can figure out the problem.  I don't see any other way to help you.

Comment: hmm. thats virtually impossible. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the popup is a vanilla VBA `MsgBox` and your Access database is in `.mdb` / `.accdb` format (e.g. no `.mde` / `.accde`), then you can do this:

Just wait for the message box to display and then press <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>.

You will see this:
[image: debug]

Press "Debug" and Access shows you the exact line in the code that triggered the `MsgBox`.